# Shell Scripting - Suppress and add lines

Tags: bash, shell

### My Shell Script

```
for ORG in `cf orgs | grep -v -e name -e Getting -e \^$ | awk '{print $1}'`
do
for SPACE in `cf org $ORG | grep spaces | awk -F \: '{print $2}' | tr -d ','`
do              
echo   "| $ORG | $SPACE |" >> $OT.md
for svc in `awk '{print $1}' serv-rpt| grep -v -e ServiceName -e \^$ | sort| uniq |tr -d ','`
do
echo -ne " | `grep -w ^$svc serv-rpt | grep $SPACE | grep $ORG |wc -l`" >> $OT.md
done
done
done
```

### Its Output

```
| cyberark-conjur-org | cyberark-conjur-space |
| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| dynatrace-org | dynatrace-space |
| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| 0| IT-dc-test | dev |
```

### Desired Output

```
| Org | Space| app-autoscaler | p-cloudcache | p-redis | p.config-server | p.mirror-service | p.mysql | p.redis | p.service-registry | scheduler-for-pcf |
| ----| ----| ----| ----| ----| ----| ----| ----| ----| ----| ---- |
| cyberark-conjur-org | cyberark-conjur-space | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0|
|  dynatrace-org | dynatrace-space | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0|
```

As you can see, my output is off by a line. Been trying to format it using different combinations of echo, but no luck so far

Comment: Please replace all images with its text.

Comment: It's rarely necessary to pipe `grep` to `awk`, since `awk` can do its own pattern matching.

Comment: Please also replace the output images with text. BTW I just removed a duplicate copy of your script from the question, not sure how that got there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `echo -n` when you're printing the beginning of each line, so it doesn't break the line before all the services.

Then echo a newline after all the services.

```
for ORG in `cf orgs | grep -v -e name -e Getting -e \^$ | awk '{print $1}'`
do
    for SPACE in `cf org $ORG | grep spaces | awk -F \: '{print $2}' | tr -d ','`
    do
        echo -n "| $ORG | $SPACE |" >> $OT.md
        for svc in `awk '{print $1}' serv-rpt| grep -v -e ServiceName -e \^$ | sort| uniq |tr -d ','`
        do
        echo -ne " | `grep -w ^$svc serv-rpt | grep $SPACE | grep $ORG |wc -l`" >> $OT.md
        done
    done
    echo ''
done
```